# How do elasticsearch aggreation return extra field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do use elasticsearch terms aggreation get a extra field value? This is my query string

```
"aggs":{
    "group_by_ruleSets":{
        "terms":{
            "size":100,
            "field":"alert.ruleSets",
            "order":{
                "_count":"desc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is elasticsearch return result:

```
"aggregations": { "terms_group_by": { "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, "sum_other_doc_count": 0, "buckets": [ { "key": "10457", "doc_count": 2 } ] } } }
```

and this is  the result I want:

```
"aggregations": { "terms_group_by": { "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, "sum_other_doc_count": 0, "buckets": [ { "key": "10457", "doc_count": 2 "setName":"Test RuleSet" } ] } } }
```

The field "setName" has in elasticsearch.

Comment: Why do you want to add extra field? What is your purpose?

Comment: Because the elasticsearch just return a Identification i have to query mysql again and convert it to display.

Comment: This is an option for structure. If you send your data to a redis server also, you dont need to get them from mysql. 

In this position, Aggregation only is for getting your identification information of document. You should use it for them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate - what is that extra field that you want and how do you want it in your response? Please provide an expected json response if possible.